# Dynamically building drop down list in php with mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

This is what I have been trying to do:

1. I have a drop down list, which I am using to select the semester.
2. Once I select the semester, in the next drop down list, relevant courses for that semester should be displayed as options.
3. It should happen each and every time I change the semester.

Database structure is as follows:

- Database - scifac
- Table -course_info
- Columns - courseID : varchar(primary key), courseName varchar, semester int.

I tried to do this using ajax by using a tutorial, but it is not working.

***This is my html page***

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<body>


<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
<!-- 
//Browser Support Code
function ajaxFunction()
{
 var ajaxRequest;  // The variable that makes Ajax possible!
 try
 {
   // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
   ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
 }
 catch (e)
 {
   // Internet Explorer Browsers
   try
   {
      ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
   }
   catch (e) 
   {
      try
      {
         ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
      catch (e)
      {
         // Something went wrong
         alert("Your browser broke!");
         return false;
      }
   }
 }
 // Create a function that will receive data 
 // sent from the server and will update
 // div section in the same page.
 ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function()
 {
   if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4)
   {
      var ajaxDisplay = document.getElementById('ajaxDiv');
      ajaxDisplay.innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;
   }

 }
 // Now get the value from user and pass it to
 // server script.
 //--------------------------------------------
 /*var age = document.getElementById('age').value;
 var wpm = document.getElementById('wpm').value;
 var sex = document.getElementById('sex').value;
 var queryString = "?age=" + age ;
 queryString +=  "&wpm=" + wpm + "&sex=" + sex;
 ajaxRequest.open("GET", "ajax-example.php" + queryString, true);
 ajaxRequest.send(null); */
 var sem=document.getElementById('year').value;
 var queryString="?sem="+sem;
 ajaxRequest.open("GET","ajax-example.php" + queryString, true);
 ajaxRequest.send(null);
}
//-->
</script>

<form name='frmform'>
        <select id='year' onchange='ajaxFunction()'>
            <option value="1">Year I Sem I</option>
            <option value="2">Year I Sem II</option>
        </select>
                <!--<input type='button' onclick='ajaxFunction()' value='Query MySQL'/>-->
        <select id="ajaxdiv">
        </select>
</form>
<!--<div id='ajaxDiv'>Your result will display here</div>-->
</body>
</html>
```

***My php page(ajax-example.php) is as follows***.

```
$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbuser = "root";
$dbpass = "";
$dbname = "scifac";

//Connect to MySQL Server
mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
//Select Database
mysql_select_db($dbname) or die(mysql_error());
// Retrieve data from Query String
$sem = $_GET['year'];
$sem=(int)$sem;

$query = "SELECT courseID FROM course_info WHERE semester = '$sem'";



//Execute query
$qry_result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());


// Insert a new row in the table for each person returned
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($qry_result)){


    $display_string.="<select>";
    $display_string.="<option>$row[courseID]</option>"; 
}
echo "Query: " . $query . "<br />";
$display_string .= "</select>";
echo $display_string;
?>
```

Your kind consideration given with this regard is highly appreciated.

Comment: Why not pull the entire dataset, and handle everything else client side?

Comment: I am not quite sure what you mean?If I am not bothering you very much, will you please give little bit of further knowledge on your answer please.

Comment: There are so many tutorials out there, but some of them make repeated trips to the database. The key to my idea is that it only makes one trip to the database, gathers the whole data set, and encodes it into, say, json.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in your ajax-example.php:

Basically you need to change $_GET['sem'] in place of $_GET['year']

```
 $dbhost = "localhost";
    $dbuser = "root";
    $dbpass = "";
    $dbname = "scifac";

    //Connect to MySQL Server
    mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
    //Select Database
    mysql_select_db($dbname) or die(mysql_error());
    // Retrieve data from Query String
    $sem = $_GET['sem'];
    //$sem=(int)$sem;

    $query = "SELECT courseID FROM course_info WHERE semester = '".$sem."'";



    //Execute query
    $qry_result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

    $display_string.="<select>";

    // Insert a new row in the table for each person returned
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($qry_result)){



        $display_string.="<option value='".$row[courseID]."'>".$row[courseID]."</option>"; 
    }

    $display_string .= "</select>";

    echo $display_string;
    ?>
```

Comment: Still it doesnt give me the correct output.Actually nothing happens.

Comment: Why do i need to change it,as there is no input from sem,The first drop down list is year

Comment: but you are sending the variable as sem in your javascript var queryString="?sem="+sem;